# chgport Command not Recognized when Running from a Process to Capture Output

Tags: windows, vb.net, output-redirect

I am trying to determine what serial ports are available using VB.NET.  When I run a batch file from the command line, it works fine.  When I try to run it and capture the output, the chgport command is not recognized as shown below

[image: error pic]

I tried changing UseShellExecute to False, but it says it needs to the true to capture the output.

I tried being very specific with the paths, even using a command shell to run the chgport command.  None of that made any difference.

**Any thoughts on what is causing the difference between running from the command line and running in a process to capture the output?**

The code snippet I'm using to capture the output:

```
    ' Fill in the com ports and file versions
    Dim oProcess As New Process()
    Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("c:\xpp_prog\ports_and_files.bat", "")
    oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    oStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
    oProcess.Start()

    Dim sOutputS As String
    Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
        sOutputS = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

    Dim sOutputE As String
    Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardError
        sOutputE = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

    MsgBox(sOutputS + sOutputE)
```

Here is the batch file:

```
@echo off
cmd /c C:\Windows\System32\chgport.exe
dir c:\xpp_prog\build_*
```

Comment: `Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c c:\xpp_prog\ports_and_files.bat") [...] Dim sOutputS = oProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() Dim sOutputE = oProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd() oProcess.WaitForExit() oProcess.Dispose()`

Comment: If you don't need port mappings or redirections, use `SerialPort.GetPortNames()`

Comment: I agree.  I also discovered you can use My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames.  Still strange how it doesn't find the chgport command, however.

Comment: If you change your code as described above, it will. In your .bat/.cmd, you can just write `C:\Windows\System32\chgport.exe` instead of `cmd /c C:\Windows\System32\chgport.exe`